# Data not appearing in database after form submission

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have created an HTML form trying to do simple registration.

The problem is that after clicking submit button no error appears but when I chech database the data from fields is not there.

signup.html

```
<form action="\polls\Registration" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group mb15">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Your Username" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb15">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb15">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb20">
                <label class="ckbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                  <span>Accept terms and conditions</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-quirk btn-block">Create Account</button>
                <br>
                <a href="/polls/signin" class="btn btn-default btn-quirk btn-stroke btn-stroke-thin btn-block btn-sign">Already a member? Sign In Now!</a>
              </div>
            </form>
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    userName= forms.CharField(label='Username',max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', max_length=100)
    fullName= forms.CharField(label='Full Name', max_length=100)
```

myview.py

```
def reg(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
         the request:
        form = forms.RegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/signin')

    else:
        form = forms.RegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [        
    url(r'^Registration', myview.reg,name='Registration'),
]
```

Comment: Where do you think you are doing anything to write data to the database?

Comment: I was thinking data submission should be in myview.py.But I think it is not possible because there is no code doing that.maybe I should have done in a model instead.Ok am new to django and python.any hint how to do please

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What is not possible? You have code for accepting the data from the form; now you actually have to *do* something with that data.

Comment: ok leme think about it

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
What I did is that I created a model to handle form processing.I also used modelForm instead of forms. For anyone having same issue check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/)